# Mapping homogeneous record type

Tags: purescript

Suppose we have a record type that is homogeneous.

```
type RecI = { a :: Int, b :: Int, c :: Int, d :: Int, e :: Int }
```

We want to get from it type with the same keys but different value type:

```
type RecS = { a :: String, b :: String, c :: String, d :: String, e :: String }
```

Is it possible to get `RecS` type without explicitly defining all the keys from `RecI`?

And the second part of the question, what is the best way to implement mapping function from one type to another:

```
mapItoS :: (Int -> String) -> RecI -> RecS
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a free-ish conversion from `Int` to `String` at type level, just give your record a parameter, then instantiate it with `Int` to get `RecI` and with `String` to get `RecS`:

```
type Rec a = { a :: a, b :: a, c :: a, d :: a, e :: a }
type RecI = Rec Int
type RecS = Rec String
```

To implement `mapItoS`, you can first convert to a [`Foreign.Object`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foreign-object/3.0.0/docs/Foreign.Object#t:Object) using [`fromHomogeneous`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foreign-object/3.0.0/docs/Foreign.Object#v:fromHomogeneous), then map the function over it, then convert back to the record.

Unfortunately there is no `toHomogeneous` function, because in general you can't be sure that the `Foreign.Object` actually contains all required keys. But no matter: in this particular case you can be sure that it does, so you can get away with [`unsafeCoerce`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-unsafe-coerce/4.0.0/docs/Unsafe.Coerce#v:unsafeCoerce):

```
mapItoS :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Rec a -> Rec b
mapItoS f = fromHomogeneous >>> map f >>> unsafeCoerce
```

Comment: Thanks that's simple. -)

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin - just a shameless plug: https://github.com/paluh/purescript-homogeneous but not published yet.... ;-)

WHITECOLOR Should I put it as a separate answer?

Comment: @paluh while I have you here, would you be so kind to merge https://github.com/paluh/purescript-undefined-is-not-a-problem/pull/9 and cut a new version so I can add it to the package set?

Answer (score 1):

A small self plug which is strictly relevant to the question :-P I've just published a library which provides many instances which allow a PureScripter to work with homogeneous `Record` and `Variant`:

https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-homogeneous

I think it should have much better inference than solutions like `heterogeneous`. Please check it out and let me know what do you think.